# Hard Drive Manufacturer Serial Numbers on a Network

Tags: networking, hard-drive

I am working on a network of over 300 laptops and I need to get all the hard drive manufacturer serial numbers connected to my network.  Is there a way to retrieve that data from the server without going to every laptop?  I am running Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can query the WMI interface on the laptops using the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, which includes a `SerialNumber` property. This property may not be available on older windows OS's (including Windows Server 2003), but should work fine when run from Server 2008, targeting any Vista or newer laptop.

Here is some general info on [WMI scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for gathering hard disk information.

Some tips:

1. have your script output to a file rather than the screen, so that you can automate it, and so you can aggregate the results.
2. run your script as a scheduled task, so that it does not stall when
   the desktop goes idle. it will take quite some time to poll 300
   devices.

Here is a sample script (not tested):

```
ComputerName = "."
Set wmiServices  = GetObject ( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" _
    & ComputerName)
' Get physical disk drive
Set wmiDisks =  wmiServices.ExecQuery ( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")
For Each wmiDisk in wmiDisks
    WScript.Echo wmiDisk.SerialNumber
Next
```